# Compiled matlab failure in windows docker container

Tags: matlab, docker

I am running compiled Matlab 2016a executables in a Windows docker container. The Matlab compiler runtime is installed in the container. This works fine when I'm executing code that doesn't require graphing.

I extended my program to include some very basic plotting logic, and it caused this exception:

```
"MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary",message:"While setting the 'Parent' property of ''Axes'':
Can't load 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\MATLAB Runtime\\v901\\bin\\win64\\osgserver.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
file:"C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\MATLAB Runtime\\v901\\mcr\\toolbox\\matlab\\graph2d\\subplot.p",name:"subplot",line:0
```

I then wrote a simpler program which simply creates a figure and plots a straight line. Running this code yields the same osgserver.dll error.

I also checked the osgserver.dll path and the file exists. This post makes me think it's an OpenGL issue:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/296652-can-t-reload-osgserver-dll

I suspect the OSG in osgserver.dll is Open Scene Graph, which seems to be some sort of graphical rendering middleware:
http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/about/features

Due to the fact that this is a docker container, I can understand why I would have trouble executing graphics code that relies on the hardware. To address this problem, I tried switching OpenGL to software and the renderer to 'painters':

```
opengl('software');
set(0, 'DefaultFigureRenderer', 'painters');
```

When I do this, I get the same osgserver.dll issue. What do I have to do to get rendering to work in a Windows docker container?

Thank you

Comment: `When I execute this code` perhaps include that code?

Comment: Any code that includes a call to subplot or plot yields the same error

Comment: Did you try to set the Parent property of the subplot to the figure handle ?

Comment: @oro777 can you explain your reasoning? I get the error when the subplot function is called, so I don't think I can get a handle to it.

Comment: how do you create the invisible figure? Does this work in the MATLAB IDE?

Comment: It's not the figure generation code. I'm just plotting a straight line in a subplot. It works in the IDE and it works with just the Matlab Compiler Runtime installed outside of a docker container. The bug has to do with rendering graphics inside a docker container

Comment: Read here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-Renderer -- MATLAB should be using the software OpenGL if it detects that it's running in a VM. But you can try `opengl software` before doing any graphics-related things.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for the idea. I had tried that already and I got the same error. It seems that osgserver.dll is required for opengl hardware or software.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.

The first step was to install Mesa as a software renderer for OpenGL. This site provides a Windows build of Mesa. Download the 64-bit version, which contains a file called opengl32.dll. Place the dll in the directory where you execute your compiled Matlab executables:

https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag

That prevented the osgserver.dll Matlab error when executing graphics code. But I still wasn't able to render OpenGL code by configuring it to use software. You would expect this code to work, but it DID NOT:

```
opengl('software');
```

I was able to get rendering to work by changing the renderer:

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureRenderer', 'painters');
```

I consider this to be a partial solution. I didn't actually get OpenGL to work. But I was able to prevent the osgserver.dll error by installing a software version of OpenGL. Changing the renderer circumvented the need for OpenGL in the first place. But using OpenGL wasn't a necessity for the project, so it addressed my need.